# How to set base class fields by copying, through method from derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Base{
public:
float a,b;
};

class Derived:public Base{
public:
int someInteger, otherInt;

void assignNthElement(vector<Base> &myArray,int i){
this=myArray[i-1];//??? How ???
}

void simpleMethodOfAssigningNthElement(vector<Base>&myArray,int i){
a=myArray[i-1].a;
b=myArray[i-1].b;
}


};
```

How to directly copy values describing Base class within derived class from myArray?
Maybe it's better to do it like it's done in "simpleMethodOfAssigningNthElement"?
Which is faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it the way you are trying in `assignNthElement`, it needs to be implemented like `simpleMethodOfAssigningNthElement` only.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign an Base class object to an Derived class object as in `assignNthElement()` that will give you a compilation error.

Note that the reverse is allowed, ie: you can assign an Derived class object to an Base class object, but that would end up slicing up the members of the derived class object. The phenomenon is called **Object Slicing**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some C-hacks, but it is bad way. Best way is simpleMethodOfAssigningNthElement.
If you want you can overload `operator=` for `Derived` class.

```
class Base{
public:
float a,b;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    int someInteger, otherInt;

    void assignNthElement(vector<Base> &myArray,int i){
        this = myArray[i-1];// It's OK now
    }

    const Derived & operator=(const Base &base){
        a=base.a;
        b=base.b;
    }

};
```